# Capturing mailchimp web hook post to SQL database

Tags: php, wordpress, mailchimp

I am trying to capture subscriptions to my MailChimp list in a database called 'wp_signup_test' on my server. The database connection is managed by WordPress. Based off the PHP template provided by MailChimp here https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/webhooks/downloads/#php I am able to write to a log file on my server. I am trying to insert the subscribe information into my database as part of the subscribe function MailChimp provided:

```
function subscribe($data){
wh_log($data['email'] . ' just subscribed!');


$mailchimp_signup = array(
        'email' => $wpdb->escape($data['email']),
        'first_name' => $wpdb->escape($data['merges']['FNAME']),
        'last_name' => $wpdb->escape($data['merges']['LNAME']),
        'phone' => $wpdb->escape($data['merges']['MMERGE4']),
        'title' => $wpdb->escape($data['merges']['MMERGE3']),
        'euid' => $wpdb->escape($data['id']),
        'leid' => $wpdb->escape($data['list_id'])
        );
$wpdb->insert(wp_signup_test, $mailchimp_signup);

}
```

I am capturing this on the log.

```
Array
(
    [key] => 238624368237658724365
    [type] => subscribe
    [fired_at] => 2016-02-22 19:19:16
    [data] => Array
       (
            [id] => bb46fb127e
            [email] => john.smith@gmail.com
            [email_type] => html
            [ip_opt] => 104.162.217.167
            [ip_signup] => 104.162.217.167
            [web_id] => 27977133
            [merges] => Array
                (
                    [FNAME] => john
                    [LNAME] => smith
                    [EMAIL] => john.smith@gmail.com
                    [MMERGE4] => 55555555
                    [MMERGE3] => Yes
                )

            [list_id] => dbf9543f8d
        )

)
```

I'm not able to capture the information in my database. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution. I was posting the insert to database code within the switch function when I should have been placing it within the conditional statement above the switch.

```
if ( !isset($_GET['key']) ){
    wh_log('No security key specified, ignoring request'); 
} elseif ($_GET['key'] != $my_key) {
    wh_log('Security key specified, but not correct:');
    wh_log("\t".'Wanted: "'.$my_key.'", but received "'.$_GET['key'].'"');
} else {

        //process the request

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if ($_POST['type'] == 'subscribe') {
            $mailchimp_signup = array(
            'email' => $wpdb->escape($_POST['data']['email']),
            'first_name' => 'test',
            'last_name' =>'test',
            'phone' => 'test',
            'title' => 'test',
            'euid' => 'test',
            'leid' => 'test'
        );

$wpdb->insert(wp_signup_test, $mailchimp_signup);


        }
    }


    wh_log('Processing a "'.$_POST['type'].'" request...');
    switch($_POST['type']){
        case 'subscribe'  : subscribe($_POST['data']);   break;
        case 'unsubscribe': unsubscribe($_POST['data']); break;
        case 'cleaned'    : cleaned($_POST['data']);     break;
        case 'upemail'    : upemail($_POST['data']);     break;
        case 'profile'    : profile($_POST['data']);     break;
        default:
            wh_log('Request type "'.$_POST['type'].'" unknown, ignoring.');
    }
}
wh_log('Finished processing request.');
```